# How to Run just-compiled program in SConscript

Tags: path, scons, build-system

I have a somewhat complex SCons build script that an some point does the following two steps:

```
# 1: builds unit tests (googletest, shell executable)
compile_tests = some_environment.Program(executable_path, test_sources)

# 2: runs unit tests (call earlier compiled program)
run_tests = other_environment.Command(
    source = executable_path,
    action = executable_path + ' --gtest_output=xml:' + test_results_path,
    target = test_results_path
)

Depends(run_tests, compile_tests)
```

This is working fine if I run scons with this build script on its own.

If I, however, invoke it via `environment.SConscript()` from another `SConstruct` file one directory level up, then step `1` adjusts the path to the project's location while step `2` doesn't. See this output:

```
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o Nuclex.Game.Native/obj/gcc-7-amd64-release/NuclexGameNativeTests -z defs -Bsymbolic Nuclex.Game.Native/obj/gcc-7-amd64-release/Tests/Timing/ClockTests.o -LNuclex.Game.Native/obj/gcc-7-amd64-release -LReferences/googletest/gcc-7-amd64-release -lNuclexGameNativeStatic -lgoogletest -lgoogletest_main -lpthread
obj/gcc-7-amd64-release/NuclexGameNativeTests --gtest_output=xml:bin/gcc-7-amd64-release/gtest-results.xml
sh: obj/gcc-7-amd64-release/NuclexGameNativeTests: No such file or directory
```

Line 2 builds the executable into `Nuclex.Game.Native/obj/gcc-7-amd64-release/` while line 3 tries to call it in `obj/gcc-7-amd64-release/`, forgetting the project directory.

Should I use another way to invoke my unit test executable? Or can I query the SCons environment for its base path?

---

Update: reproduction case, place https://pastebin.com/W08yZuF9 as `SConstruct` in root directory, create subdirectory `somelib` and place https://pastebin.com/eiP63Yxh as `SConstruct` therein, also create `main.cpp` with a "Hello World" or other dummy program.

Comment: I would not call what you have currently a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Have these environments (some_environment, other_environment) been modified in any way? What are the values of executable_path and test_results_path?

Comment: Also were there any args to the call to SConscript?

Comment: I believe the example is sufficient to understand and reproduce the issue. Assume the environments are vanilla and substitute `a` and `b` for `executable_path` and `test_results_path` if you wish. I have now also added two minimal `SConstruct` files to reproduce the issue at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I tried out your repro case and everything seemed to be working correctly. Are you sure your not using a variant dir anywhere? your path ```obj/gcc-7-amd64-release/``` suggests you are? and there are no differences in the environments, then why not use the same environment?

Comment: My actual build setup does use VariantDir, but the issue hinges on the `environment.SConscript()` call. On my system, the minimal reproduction case errors out with `sh: ./example: No such file or directory`.

Comment: My mistake, the repro is giving me that too, I had changed the action to just echo the file output target because it was building the example in the expected location. To fix the repro you should use $SOURCE in place of ./example in the action. Not sure if that will fix it in the real thing.

Comment: Works in the real build script, too. Make it an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Can you copy your repros into the question.  They're quite small and it'd be easier to read if their inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SCons Action (the `action` parameter in the Command) will use the SCons variables to substitute sources and targets in correctly, taking into account VariantDirs and SConscript directories automatically. You can find more info on these source and target substitutions here: https://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html#variable_substitution

There is a section which explains using this in regards to SConscript and VariantDirs:

> SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='sub/dir')
>   $SOURCE              => sub/dir/file.x
>   ${SOURCE.srcpath}    => src/file.x
>   ${SOURCE.srcdir}     => src

So in your example I think you want to replace `executable_path` with `$SOURCE` in the action string:

```
# 2: runs unit tests (call earlier compiled program)
run_tests = other_environment.Command(
    source = executable_path,
    action = '$SOURCE --gtest_output=xml:$TARGET',
    target = test_results_path
)
```